# XML Validation. Too many open files

Tags: java, xml, file, exception

I have written a program to validate all the xmls present in a folder and report the failed ones.I have used the java XML validator utility in my program.

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File("xsdPath"));
```

I have a list of xml files which I am validating in a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String returnValue = validateXML(list.get(i));
    ...
}
```

Then I have a function which Validates the XML's

```
public static String validateXML(String xmlPath){
    try {
        validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
}
```

The above function returns too many open files error in case it exceeds the system limit of the max number of files set.

If i change the linux parameter by using ulimit -n 3000 then its working fine. I want to know whether we can use a different way to validate the XML in the java code itself so that I need not change the system parameter.

Comment: what about not opening 3000 files at once?

Comment: You need to close the StreamSource when you are done with it.

Comment: I would say, if you need to close the InputStream yourself then that's a bug. Saxon applies the rule that whoever creates an InputStream is responsible for closing it. When you use `new StreamSource(File)`, the system is creating the stream, therefore the system should close it. But the JAXP documentation isn't explicit on that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to keep track of the underlying `InputStream`, so that you can close it when you're done :

```
public static String validateXML(String xmlPath){

    BufferedInputStream xmlStream = null;
    try {
        validator = schema.newValidator();
        xmlStream=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(xmlPath));
        Source src=new StreamSource(xmlStream);
        validator.validate(src);
    } catch (IOException e) {

       // do something
    }
    finally{

        if(xmlStream != null){

            try{
                xmlStream.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){

               // error while closing
            }            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon : Yes you're right, I secured this part a bit .

Answer (score 2):

@Berger is correct in his answer, however if you're using Java 7 or higher, you can use the try-with-resource functionality to significantly cut down on your boilerplate exception- and resource-handling code:

```
public static String validateXML(String xmlPath){
    validator = schema.newValidator();
    try (BufferedInputStream xmlStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(xmlPath))) {
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlStream));
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

More details here:

[The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)